# How to remove all the lines of text before a specific text and all those after another specific text in multiple files using notepad++ or TextCrawler?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I am working with a set of  reports as txt files for a project. But these text files contain a few lines of unwanted text before and after the actual report.Required portion of every text file starts with the string "Start of report on" and ends with "End of report on". I need to remove all the text before "Start of report" and those after "End of report" in  all the txt files simultaneously. I tried using .*(?=Start of report) to remove all text before "Start of report" but it removed only the text in the same line. I am non-tech guy and suck at Regex. Can anyone guide me?

Example text file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
In eget semper eros. Fusce efficitur elit quis vestibulum pretium. 
Curabitur tristique commodo dui sed molestie.
***Start of Report on -------***
Vivamus porttitor dolor felis, at varius dolor placerat vehicula. Donec non dictum nulla. Maecenas vitae dolor quis ligula scelerisque accumsan. Vestibulum vehicula dolor dolor, id porta orci maximus a.

Aenean finibus enim in magna tristique bibendum. Suspendisse eleifend purus nibh, eget tincidunt est venenatis vitae. Morbi venenatis massa at lectus tincidunt, eget faucibus neque sollicitudin.

Morbi feugiat erat eros, fringilla convallis nulla euismod in. Fusce consectetur dapibus libero, nec vestibulum est feugiat a. Vivamus nec commodo purus, sit amet egestas nunc. Nulla ac ipsum nec risus facilisis sollicitudin.
***End of report on ---------***
Sed euismod tristique nunc non suscipit. Nullam blandit justo sed erat placerat fringilla. Etiam felis nunc, aliquam sit amet fermentum quis, pellentesque ac nisi.
```

---

Expected result:

```
***Start of Report on -------***
Vivamus porttitor dolor felis, at varius dolor placerat vehicula. Donec non dictum nulla. Maecenas vitae dolor quis ligula scelerisque accumsan. Vestibulum vehicula dolor dolor, id porta orci maximus a.

Aenean finibus enim in magna tristique bibendum. Suspendisse eleifend purus nibh, eget tincidunt est venenatis vitae. Morbi venenatis massa at lectus tincidunt, eget faucibus neque sollicitudin.

Morbi feugiat erat eros, fringilla convallis nulla euismod in. Fusce consectetur dapibus libero, nec vestibulum est feugiat a. Vivamus nec commodo purus, sit amet egestas nunc. Nulla ac ipsum nec risus facilisis sollicitudin.
***End of report on ---------***
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Find: `\A[\s\S]+(?=Start of report)`; Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Comment: Find: `\A[\s\S]+(Start of report[\s\S]+?End of report on.*$)[\s\S]+`; Replace: `$1`

Comment: Thanks a ton Toto. The first expression for the beginning of the text worked perfectly. But the second one failed to find the strings. Guess I  will have to run it once for the beginning and once for the end (which is not a problem) So I tried ?End of report on.*$[\s\S]+ which showed an error -Quantifier{x,y} following nothing.

Comment: It works for me. You can remove `\A` from the beginning of regex. You have to click on `Replace all`. Also, try it with `Match case` unchecked. In your second try, remove the question mark.

Comment: Thanks a ton Toto. Worked with \A removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[\s\S]+(Start of report[\s\S]+?End of report on.*$)[\s\S]+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[\s\S]+                 # 1 or more any character
(                       # start group 1
  Start of report         # literally
  [\s\S]+                 # 1 or more any character
  End of report on        # literally
  .*                      # 0 or more any character but newline
  $                       # end of line
)                       # end group 1
[\s\S]+                 # 1 or more any character
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. the text to keep)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Toto. Appreciate you taking time to explain the steps and their meaning. The world needs more people like you.

Comment: @KrishnaChandran: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)